# How to select only one field from database in sqlite in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite

I am using Flutter and using sqflite package, and I am trying to create a query to get an integer value from a database but it is giving me an error:

Here is the code:

```
Future<int> getCurrencyRate(String symb) async{
Database db = await instance.database;
return await db.rawQuery("Select rate from Currencies where symb= '$symb'");
}
```

It is showing this error:

**A value of type 'List<Map<String, Object?>>' can't be returned from the method 'getCurrencyRate' because it has a return type of 'Future'**

How can I make the function return an int (which is the result of the query) instead of a list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<double> getCurrencyRate(String symb) async{
    final db = await instance.database;
    final result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT rate FROM Currencies WHERE symb = '$symb'");
    return result.isNotEmpty ? result.first["rate"] : 0.0;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, it is showing this error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from the method 'getCurrencyRate' because it has a return type of 'Future<double>'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider going through Stack Overflow's help section in order to know how to answer a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.